# How to fix the sound of the hard drive needle when turning off the system

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, sata

I have recently replaced the main HDD of my ASUS a53s laptop with an SSD. I have placed the HDD hard drive in the SATA port where the DVD drive was located. I have not had any problems and the speed of my system has increased a lot. However, I have noticed that every time I turn off the system, a click of the needle of the HDD hard disk sounds, as if it were turned off suddenly (this did not happen when it was placed in the main SATA port). Could you do some configuration in Ubuntu to avoid this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have been able to find an intermediate solution that is to put the hard disk in stand-by shortly after starting the system with gnome-disk-utility (for it to work you have to enter a minimum time of 5 minutes or more). However, it does not seem like a real solution, since the needle of the hard disk should naturally come to rest before turning off the system.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to fix it by adding the command `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sdb` in the "Start Applications" menu, and configuring sudoers not to ask for superuser password. In this way I indicate that the HDD is put in stand-by at login, at shutdown and at restart.

To configure sudoers look at the following link: [[Start command as superuser at login (SOLVED)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228670/start-command-as-superuser-at-login-solved]).