# Start command as superuser at login

Tags: xfce, startup-applications

How can I start a command as superuser at startup on Xubuntu? Normally I enter any command in the option 'Session and Startup -> Application Autostart', but I don't know how to do it as superuser since if I enter the command preceded by sudo or pkexec nothing happens (I also don't want to be asked for the password at startup, since I have already logged in).

Comment: Does the command require a display for output? Or is it headless?

Comment: I'm not sure which display manager (DM) Xubuntu uses, but you might want to look at the session-setup-script hook or equivalent. See for example [How to execute command before user login on linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450836/65304)

Comment: Copy its .desktop file to `/etc/xdg/autostart` or create a .desktop file in that folder.

Comment: Read `man sudoers` to see passwordless `root` for a single command.

Comment: The command that I want to run at startup is [sudo hdparm -y / dev / sdb] so that one of my hard drives stays in stand-by at startup. @Terrance I have seen the folder you mention but I do not have enough knowledge to create a .desktop file since I do not know how to complete the data that appears within each one. Thank you.

Comment: add cmds to /etc/rc.local . then type "sudo systemctl enable rc-local"

Answer (score 2):

I've finally fixed it by adding the `hdparm` command in sudoers. For this I have run `sudo visudo` and added the following line (important that it be added to the end of the file for the rule to apply): `MY_USER ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/hdparm`, replacing "MY_USER" by my user.

Once this is done we can add the command in the "Start Applications" menu. The command must also have "sudo" in front.

In this thread there is a very similar case: [[Run script as root immediately after login to gui](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738640/run-script-as-root-immediately-after-login-to-gui?noredirect=1&lq=1])